# mysql select, count, left join and show

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have to make a mysql interrogation and i must to count some cell with same value, by date and left join other infos from orther table.

table1

```
col1 | col2     | col3
ALEX | today    | finished
JOHN | today    | finished
TIM  | today    | finished
JOHN | today    | unfinished
JOHN | today    | finished
TIM  | tommorow | finished
```

table2

```
col4 | col5
ALEX | mail1@website.tld
JOHN | mail1@website.tld
TIM  | mail1@website.tld
```

i tried this code:

```
sql="
SELECT col2
     , col1
     , col3
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM table1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2  
    ON table1.task_cine = table2.col4 
 WHERE table1.col3='finished' 
 GROUP 
    BY col1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql.mysql_error());
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "user : ";
    echo $rows['col1'];
    echo ", on date: ";
    echo $rows['col2'];
    echo " have ";
    echo $row['COUNT(*)'];
    echo " finished, and have email address";
    echo $rows['col5'];
}
```

can you help me, please? I'm trying to understand php, but is difficult.

Comment: Give COUNT(*) an alias, like `total` - and see about PHP's modern APIs (PDO or mysqli_). Also, it's good practice to qualify which table a column comes from - so `table1.col3`, etc.

Comment: Are you sure that the mentioned column  `task_cine` belongs to `table1` ?

Comment: in SQL, is ON table1.col1 = table2.col4  , sorry. but still not show $rows['col5']

Comment: You forgot to add `$` sign to your variable `sql`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :-
mysql_fetch_assoc($result)

instead of 
mysql_fetch_array($result)

or

use index with array parameters for mysql_fetch_array($result)

as $rows[0], $rows[1]

Comment: is showme just col1 end other text, nothing else (other $rows[]).

Comment: yes, in code i have $row, not $rows and i modified. it works, but $rows['col5'] still not working.

Comment: `$rows['col5']` is not working because you are not selecting it in your SQL query. You also should use `echo $rows['COUNT(*)'];` instead of `echo $row['COUNT(*)'];` because your dataset is `$rows`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$sql="
SELECT col1
     , col2
     , col5
     , COUNT(*) 
  FROM table1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN table2  
    ON table1.task_cine = table2.col4 
 WHERE table1.col3='finished' 
 GROUP 
    BY col1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql.mysql_error());
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "user : ";
    echo $rows['col1'];
    echo ", on date: ";
    echo $rows['col2'];
    echo " have ";
    echo $rows['COUNT(*)'];
    echo " finished, and have email address";
    echo $rows['col5'];
}
```